# Imported products not visible in front-end

Tags: magento, import

I am importing products using the same csv template that I have for 3 years. But now, Magento imports alright without throwing an error, and the products appear okay in the grid on the frontend. However, when I click on the product in the grid, the product detail page shows 'Page not found'.

I am using CE 1.7.0.2, and have reindexed the data after import, cleared Magento cache, etc. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

-TM

Comment: Check magento log and server log and browser console

Comment: ok, so what should I be looking for in each of these? Especially the browser console?

Comment: In browser console check under Net what is the response.

Comment: ok, so the Network tab in the browser console showed all OK as each record was uploaded. However, at the end, it shows this error: POST error; index.php/admin/system_convert_gui/batchFinish/id/179/key/c1273546474747/  500 Server error. What does this mean, and how do I fix this? Thanks.